# Question bookmarks are not removed if my account is deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bookmarks, deleted-accounts

I can add an indefinite number of bookmarks to a question by bookmarking the question, deleting my account, and repeating. Bookmarks are not removed on account deletion. Is this behavior intentional? So if I bookmark my question and delete my account, those bookmarks are permanent?

Comment: I don't think this is intentional, as this can be used to game the Favorite Question and Stellar Question badges.

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog Do you think it should be fixed to keep users from farming those badges? It's not really like badges give you extra reputation or extra privileges so is it really necessary?

Comment: Yes, I think bookmarks by a user should be removed when their account is removed, if their votes aren't preserved when deleting.

Comment: This has been added to the bug queue that our team is currently working on.

Answer (score 5):

As best as I can tell, this does not happen. When a user is deleted, all of their bookmark votes are deleted as well. There is another scheduled task that brings Post Bookmark counts up to date (in a denormalized column on the `Posts` table) - so you can see a lag of a few hours between when a user is deleted and when their Bookmarks are removed from the count showing up on the post.

There is the possibility of abuse here when it comes to receiving the `Favorite Questions` and `Stellar Question` badges (a user can create accounts just for the purpose of adding bookmarks to their own question in order to win these badges).

However, an examination of badges awarded does not show that this has been abused at all (yet…). So in the meantime, there is no code logic to change, and we will not be removing any awarded badges (even from the very small number of posts that received the badge and then dipped back below the threshold due to deleted user accounts or removed bookmarks).

Comment: Are the badges awarded based on denormalized score, or based on actual votes?

Comment: Badges awarded based on actual votes. Denormalized bookmark count is only used for display purposes.